# Wordpress/WoOCommerce Changed search-slug: Want to search/show results from specific custom type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Search is set via Relevanssi plugin to only search for the custom type "brands". However, using this code beneath to change the url slug makes it search everything except custom types. How can I alter the code to search specifically in the "brands" custom type?

```
function change_sok_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/sok/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_sok_url' );

function rewrite_sok_slug() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'sok(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?s=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[6]',
         'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_sok_slug' );
```

Comment: Is it a premium plugin? Might help. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-form-to-search-only-within-a-custom-taxnomy/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: @little_coder Yes it's premium. It's wokring as intented. However my code searches all. I want it only for a specific custom type.

Comment: Have you tried adding this to form? `<input type="hidden" name="post_types" value="brands" >` [link here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-form-to-search-only-within-a-custom-taxnomy/)